# Unable to read from file from argv

Tags: c, file, argv

I am trying to read from a file, and here is my code, but as I run my code nothing shows up. Have I used the `getline()` function incorrectly? I can not understand my problem.

```
const char *READ = "r";
    
    /**
     * main - Entry point of my program
     *
 * Return: On success, it returns 0. On
 * error it returns -1
 */
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
        FILE *fpointer;
        char *lineptr = NULL;
        size_t *n = 0;
        int line_number = 1;

        if (ac != 2)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: monty file\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        fpointer = fopen(av[1], READ);
        if (fpointer == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't open file %s\n", av[1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        while (getline(&lineptr, n, fpointer) != -1)
        {
                printf("Line %d: %s\n", line_number, lineptr);
                line_number++;
        }
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: I think the fopen syntax is incorrect. Should be `fopen("filename", "r")` from what i know.

Comment: @al366io Have a better look.

Comment: `n` should be `size_t`, not `size_t*`. Then pass `&n` to `getline`. Otherwise you would have to allocate memory for `n` to point to

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, it has worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Gerhardh That should be an answer so it can be accepted...

Answer (score 1):

`getline(&lineptr, n, fpointer)` returns `-1`.  You did not explicitly check this and print an error message.

Checking `errno` it's because of `EINVAL`: invalid argument.  Also good to check `errno`.

Reason is that `n` is `NULL`, while a pointer to an existing `size_t` is required.

BTW, indenting with 8 spaces is rather uncommon; I'd stay with 4 space.  (Also, never use TAB characters.)

It's advisable to stick with extremely common `argc` and `argv`.

Nice you put `{`s on a further empty line; I like that style.

You'd get this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

const char *READ = "r";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fpointer;
    char *lineptr = NULL;
    size_t n;
    int line_number = 1;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: monty file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fpointer = fopen(argv[1], READ);
    if (fpointer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't open file '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (getline(&lineptr, &n, fpointer) == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to read file '%s': %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Line %4d: %s\n", line_number, lineptr);
        line_number++;
    }
    while (getline(&lineptr, &n, fpointer) != -1);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: @DevSolar I was too quick and deleted my answer and in the mean time sorted out the issue.

Comment: @iii I was too quick and deleted my answer and in the mean time sorted out the issue.

Comment: @hyde I had a working version on my computer, but copy-pasted from above and forgot the correction.  All good now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of `getline`:

```c
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

As an output parameter, the type of `n` is `size_t *`. It points to a space for writing by `getline`.

But in your code, `n` points to `0`, which is NOT a vaild addr to write in.